# SQL sum query not working not working. Returning NULL

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to obtain the sum of used channels. can anyone see what is wrong with my code?
$spacefreenvr variable returns nothing (blank) when result should be 144 from the 3 rows in the database.

```
$nvrlisting = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(usedchannel) AS usedchan FROM CCTVequip WHERE customer LIKE ? AND equipserial LIKE ?");
$filtertype = "NVR%";
$nvrlisting->bind_param('ss', $camclient, $filtertype);
$nvrlisting->execute();
$spacecount = $nvrlisting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$spacefreenvr = $spacecount['usedchan'];
$nvrlisting->close();
```

Comment: You would get `NULL` if the `WHERE` clause filtered out all rows.

Comment: What about `$camclient`? Is it initialized? You can replace `SUM(usedchannel)` with `coalesce(SUM(usedchannel), 0)` to receive more consistent results.

Comment: Hello,  There are 3 rows which match the query. where customer and serial number starting with NVR

I use a SELECT * query succesfully with the $camclient, so all is good with the filtering.

I also removed the WHERE portion of the query to sum all rows in that column (over 300 rows) and still returned BLANK. So Im guessing the error is somewhere else in the code

Comment: You are mixing PDO and mysqli. You should be getting PHP errors. Have you got PHP error reporting enabled?

Comment: I have now! yes, I can see where the PDO is mixed with mysqli. Its giving me an unexpected paramater on the ->fetch line.

What do you suggest should be the correct command?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thankyou to Dharman. your comment inspired me to review it completely.

I now have the query returning the correct value after doing more research.
I now understand that using the SUM function in sql query returns a single row / single column result which I could just bind to a variable.

This worked.

```
$nvrlisting = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(usedchannel) AS usedchan FROM CCTVequip WHERE customer LIKE ? AND equipserial LIKE ?");
$filtertype = "NVR%";
$nvrlisting->bind_param('ss', $camclient, $filtertype);
$nvrlisting->execute();
$nvrlisting->store_result();
$nvrlisting->bind_result($total);
$nvrlisting->fetch();
$spacefreenvr = $total;
$nvrlisting->close();
```